# I want to calculate the area of the polygon formed according to the number of points written, provided that it is a maximum of 4 points

Tags: python

I want to calculate the area of the polygon formed according to the number of points written, provided that it is a maximum of 4 points.

```
import math

class Point: #This class is correct
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


point1 = Point(int(input()), int(input()))  # Point(x,y)
point2 = Point(int(input()), int(input()))


def to_point(point1: Point, point2: Point):
    res = math.sqrt(((point1.x - point2.x) ** 2) + ((point1.y - point2.y) ** 2))
    return res

print(to_point(point1, point2))
```

I'm having trouble with the code below.

```
class Polygon(Point):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self.x,self.y)

point_a=Point(int(input()),int(input()))
point_b = Point(int(input()), int(input()))
point_c = Point(int(input()), int(input()))
point_d= Point(int(input()), int(input()))

def get_Area(self,point_a: Polygon,point_b:Polygon,point_c: Polygon,point_d:Polygon):
    print("Enter the number of point")
    n=int(input())
    if n==2:
        print(to_point(point_a, point_b))
    elif n==3:
        return abs(((point_a.x*point_b.y)+(point_b.x*point_c.y)+(point_c.x*point_a.y))-((point_b.x*point_a.y)+(point_c.x*point_b.y)+(point_a.x*point_c.y)))*0.5
    elif n==4:
        return #I can't calculate area for 4 points
print(get_Area(point_a,point_b,point_c,point_d)) '''
```

Comment: The area of a quadrilateral has several cases that need to be considered. For ease of implementation and testing you can focus on one, and extend accordingly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral

Comment: The area of a polygon with 2 points is 0.  You're calculating the length of the line, not the area of the polygon.

Comment: you want to program yourself? if not, try shapely

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
elif n==4:
    return abs((point_a.x*point_b.y - point_a.y*point_b.x) +
               (point_b.x*point_c.y - point_b.y*point_c.x) + 
               (point_c.x*point_d.y - point_c.y*point_d.x) +
               (point_d.x*point_a.y - point_d.y*point_a.x)) / 2;
```

It doesn't work for self intersecting polygons, that you can't express with just one formula. You could potentially calculate the intersection point and use the formula for triangles to calculate the area, as you always get 2 triangles in intersecting quadrilateral. There would also be special cases like when all the points are in line, but that could be resolved by sanitizing the input.

Check out https://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea.html